# How to download srt files from websites like 'Subscene.com' using python (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a subtitle downloader which takes the name of all the files in the folder and searches on the website 'Subscene.com'.
I am able to get to scrap the HTML source using beautiful soup but i am unable to get the link for the zip file from the HTML source. Downloading gets triggered by clicking on the 'Download Button'.

[image: The higlighted text is the link which the download button redirects to. But how i am supposed to download the file using this link]

There is no such explicit link for the zip file to download.
Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: The site is likely using click events on the button, rather than setting a download link. Probably to avoid having people scrape and download their content easily.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the javascript code. Possibly, you could get the link using some regex.

Comment: Add an actual link

Comment: That's the page where the download button is -   https://subscene.com/subtitles/the-big-bang-theory-first-season/english/136037

Answer (score 1):

You don't want any explicit link for download zip file

Here is the logic I used for my python downloader script

```
MyFile2= urllib2.urlopen( Your Url ) # input link

MyHtml2 = MyFile2.read()

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(MyHtml2,"lxml")

downloaddiv= soup2.find("div", {"class": "download"}) #finding div class for the link

downloadlink = downloaddiv.find('a') #finding url from div class

download = 'https://subscene.com/'+downloadlink['href'] #appending the above url to main domain for genrating download

r = requests.get(download) # Request for downloading

z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content)) # Opening zip file

z.extractall() # extracting zip file
```

You will also need these headerfiles

```
import zipfile
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import lxml.html
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib import urlopen
import requests ,io
```

Hope you understand everything correct!!